# Shift register with BlockRAM - XILINX

Tags: vhdl

I'm very new to VHDL targeting XILINX solutions. Reading XST [manual](https://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/sw_manuals/xilinx14_4/xst_v6s6.pdf) (page 155) I see example to implement shift register on BlockRAM.

```
entity srl_512_bram is 
  generic ( 
    LENGTH     : integer := 512; 
    ADDRWIDTH : integer := 9; 
    WIDTH      : integer := 8); 
 port ( 
    CLK        : in  std_logic; 
    SHIFT_IN  : in  std_logic_vector(WIDTH-1 downto 0); 
    SHIFT_OUT : out std_logic_vector(WIDTH-1 downto 0)); 
end srl_512_bram; 

architecture behavioral of srl_512_bram is 

  signal CNTR : std_logic_vector(ADDRWIDTH-1 downto 0); 
  signal SHIFT_TMP : std_logic_vector(WIDTH-1 downto 0); 
  type ram_type is array (0 to LENGTH-3) of std_logic_vector(WIDTH-1 downto 0); 
  signal RAM : ram_type := (others => (others => ’0’)); 
begin 

  counter : process (CLK) 
  begin 
    if CLK’event and CLK = ’1’ then 
       if CNTR = conv_std_logic_vector(LENGTH-3, ADDRWIDTH)  then 
         CNTR <= (others => ’0’); 
       else 
         CNTR <= CNTR + ’1’; 
       end if; 
    end if; 
  end process counter; 

  memory : process (CLK) 
  begin 
    if CLK’event and CLK = ’1’ then 
       RAM(conv_integer(CNTR)) <= SHIFT_IN; 
       SHIFT_TMP                 <= RAM(conv_integer(CNTR)); 
       SHIFT_OUT                 <= SHIFT_TMP; 
    end if; 
  end process memory; 

end behavioral;
```

Few questions I find there:

- how is it obvious that BlockRAM is/will be included in design (ie synthesis) ?
- as two processes here work in parallel, which one will start first, knowing that both start on positive CLK edge ?
- my perspective is that "memory" process doesn't provide shifting, but rather SHIFT_IN vector insertion at "current" RAM position (the one indexed with CNTR). Where is shifting in this code ?

Comment: I would strongly propose simulating this code. You'll most likely understand what happens without any explanation.

Comment: Very likely. It is my bad habit to first read new matter, then to try.

Comment: Which process will start first? That is undefined. You don't know. BUT, you don't need to know. Why? Because the left hand side of a _signal assignment_ (`<=`) is not updated until _all_ processes have finished executing. So, it doesn't matter which order processes execute in.

Comment: Huh- that's new to me. Than you suggest that "RAM(conv_integer(CNTR))" will regard to new CNTR (as defined in "counter" process) ?

Answer (score 1):

> how is it obvious that BlockRAM is/will be included in design (ie synthesis) ?

[AR# 46515](https://www.xilinx.com/support/answers/46515.html) from Xilinx says to try [UG627](https://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/sw_manuals/xilinx12_1/xst.pdf). These references may not be exactly what you're using and possibly a few years dated, but the concepts in them are good. In UG627 have a look near page 170. There's some example VHDL explaining how BRAM is inferred, and it's very similar to what you have here.

> as two processes here work in parallel, which one will start first, knowing that both start on positive CLK edge ?

Remember this VHDL turns into dedicated hardware, so both processes have their own circuitry on the FPGA and legitimately happen at the same time. When I was learning VHDL this tripped me up for quite a while - and if I'm honest it still gets me from time to time - so maybe the best approach here is actually to simulate the design and then try to rationalize what the VHDL is doing based on the waveforms.

Also, I don't want to confuse you more, but maybe this helps --> you could just as easily re-write the `counter` and `memory` processes as follows. In this case, the code is processed one line at a time (sequentially) as you may expect, but *VERY IMPORTANT* the signals are not physically updated until *after* the entire process has completed.

```vhdl
counter_and_memory_combined : process (CLK) 
begin 
    if CLK’event and CLK = ’1’ then 
        -- From the counter process
        if CNTR = conv_std_logic_vector(LENGTH-3, ADDRWIDTH)  then 
            CNTR <= (others => ’0’); 
        else 
            CNTR <= CNTR + ’1’; 
        end if; 

        -- From the memory process
        RAM(conv_integer(CNTR)) <= SHIFT_IN; 
        SHIFT_TMP               <= RAM(conv_integer(CNTR)); 
        SHIFT_OUT               <= SHIFT_TMP; 
    end if; 
end process memory;
```

Sometimes it's easier to look at VHDL when you combine like this, though I'm definitely NOT saying this is always the best approach. Sometimes it makes the code more cluttered.

> my perspective is that "memory" process doesn't provide shifting, but rather SHIFT_IN vector insertion at "current" RAM position (the one indexed with CNTR). Where is shifting in this code ?

The code you posted might be clearer if `SHIFT_IN` was re-labeled `DATA_IN` and `SHIFT_OUT` to `DATA_OUT` (and `SHIFT_TMP` to `DATA_TMP`). So, "shifting" in this case means that the data `SHIFT_IN` gets stored into `RAM`, and the data that was already in `RAM` gets shifted out to `SHIFT_OUT`.

Comment: No, I considered this as word shifting, because SHIFT_IN is vector. And the article title says its about shifting.

Comment: The SHIFT_IN is the new value that gets stored into RAM.  The SHIFT_OUT is what was in RAM when you do the store.  Data gets "shifted" in and the old data gets "shifted" out. I'll edit my answer to be more clear about that.